# Calculate sum of small values

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim _{n\to \infty} x_n = -\infty$. I need to calculate 
$$x=\log \sum _{n=1}^\infty e^{x_n}$$ 
using computer arithmetic. The problem is that all $e^{x_n}$'s are almost zero, which results in $x=-\infty$. Which approaches are common for this situation?

Currently, I am using an approximation $x\approx \max_n x_n$, but it is very rough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [log-sum-exp trick](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/blog/2013/01/09/computing-log-sum-exp/):
$$\begin{align}
\log\sum_n\exp x_n &= \log\sum_n\exp\bigl((x_n-a)+a\bigr) \\
&= \log\sum_n\bigl(\exp(x_n-a)\exp(a)\bigr) \\
&= \log\Bigl(\exp(a)\sum_n\exp(x_n-a)\Bigr) \\
&= \log\exp(a) + \log\sum_n\exp(x_n-a) \\
&= a + \log\sum_n\exp(x_n-a)
\end{align}$$
Now pick $a=\max_n x_n$.